# Efficient data structure for sparse data lookup

Tags: c++, algorithm

Situation:

Given some points with coordinate (x, y) 
Range 0 < x < 100,000,000 and 0 < y <100,000,000

I have to find smallest square which contains at least N no of points on its edge and inside it.

1. I used vector to store coordinates and searched all squares with side length minLength upto side length maxLength (Appling Brute Force in relevant space)

   ```
   struct Point
   {
           int x;
           int y;
   };

   vector<Point> P;
   int minLength = sqrt(N) - 1;
   int maxLength = 0;

   //   bigx= largest x coordinate of any point
   //   bigy= largest y coordinate of any point
   //   smallx= smallest x coordinate of any point
   //   smally= smallest y coordinate of any point

   (bigx - smallx) < (bigy - smally) ? maxLength = (bigx - smallx) : maxLength = (bigy - smally);
   ```
2. For each square I looked up, traversed through complete vector to see if at least N points are on its edge and inside it.

This was quite time inefficient.

Q1. What data structure should I use to improve time efficiency without changing Algorithm I used?
Q2. Efficient Algorithm for this problem?

Comment: Interesting question. I wonder if the problem is NP-hard.

Comment: You might find some useful ideas in the "*n* (or *k*) nearest neighbour" problem, with the [unifrom norm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L-infinity_norm) used for distance.

Comment: @NPE: Not at all. The input domain can be sorted, and it turns out that's the hardest part. From there it's fancy counting.

Comment: NPE: Surely not, there's clearly a polynomial time algorithm: Given a solution square, we can shrink it while still containing the same points until three of its sides contain a point from the set. So by considering all 3-subsets of points, we can find the square.

Comment: [This paper](http://pubman.mpdl.mpg.de/pubman/item/escidoc:1834660:2/component/escidoc:1857755/MPI-I-93-116.pdf) presents  a O(n log n + kn log^2 k) algorithm for the problem, where n is the number of points and k is the number of points that have to be inside the square

Answer (score 2):

There are points on 2 opposite edges - if not, you could shrink the square by 1 and still contain the same number of points. That means the possible coordinates of the edges are limited to those of the input points. The input points are *probably* not on the corners, though. (For a minimum rectangle, there would be points on all 4 edges as you can shrink one dimension without altering the other)

The next thing to realize is that each point divides the plane in 4 quadrants, and each quadrant contains a number of points. (These can add up to more than the total number of points as the quadrants have one pixel overlap). Lets say that NW(p) is the number of points to the northwest of point p, i.e. those that have `x>=px and y>=py`. Then the number of points in a square is `NW(bottomleft) + NW(topright) - NW(bottomright) - NW(topleft)`.

It's fairly easy to calculate `NW(p)` for all input points. Sort them by `x` and for equal `x` by  `y`. The most northwestern point has `NW(p)==0`. The next point can have `NW(p)==1` if it's to the southeast of the first point, else it has `NW(p)==0`. It's also useful to keep track of SW(p) in this stage, as you're working through the points from west to east and they're therefore not sorted north to south. Having calculated `NW(p)`, you can determine the number of points in a square S in `O(1)`

Recall that the square size is restricted by by the need to have points on opposite edges. Assume the points are on the left (western) and right edge - you still have the points sorted by x order. Start by assuming the left edge is at your leftmost x coordinate, and see what the right edge must be to contain N points. Now shift the left edge to the next x coordinate and find a new right edge (and thus a new square). Do this until the right edge of the square is the rightmost point.

Its also possible that the square is constrained in y direction. Just sort the points in y direction and repeat, then choose the smallest square between the two outcomes.

Since you're running linearly through the points in x and y direction, that part is just O(N) and the dominant factor is the O(N log N) sort.

Comment: "Start by assuming the left edge is at your leftmost x coordinate, and see what the right edge must be to contain N points." I think this is not trivial. The number of points in the square depends on the vertical position of the square, not just it's width. Furthermore, we can't proof that one of the points in the square must be on one of its corners, so I don't see how to perform this step

Answer (score 1):

Look at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Space_partitioning for algorithms that use the Divide-and-Conquer technique to solve this. This is definitely solvable in Polynomial time.

---

Another variant algorithms can be on the following lines.

- Generate a vornoi-diagram on the points to get neighbour information. [ O(nlog(n)) ]
- Now use Dynamic Programming, the DP will be similar to the problem of finding the maximum subarray in a 2D array. Here instead of the sum of numbers, you will keep count of points before it.

  2.a Essentially a recursion similar to this will hold.  [ O(n) ]

> Number of elements in square from (0,0) to (x,y ) = (Number of elems
>   from square (0,0 to ((x-1),y))+ (Number of elems in square 0,0 - ( x, y-1))
>   - (Number of elems in (0,0)-((x-1),(y-1)))

Your recurrence will have to change for all the points on its neighbourhood and to the left and above, instead of just the points above and left as above.

- Once the DP is ready, you can query the points in a sqare in O(1). 
  Another O(n^2) loop to find from all possible combinations and find the least square.
- You can even greedily start from the smallest squares first, that way you can end your search as soon as you find a suitable square..

---

Answer (score 1):

The [rtree](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/R-tree) allows spatial searching, but doesn't have stl implementation, although sqlite would allow binding.  This can answer "get all points within range", "k nearest neighbours"

Finding a region which has the most dense data, is a problem similar to clustering.

Iterating over the points and finding the N nearest entries to each point.  Then generate the smallest circle - centre would be the Max(x) - min(x), Max(y) - min(y).  A square can be formed which contains all the neighbours, and would be somewhere between 2r length and 2sqrt(r) length sides compared to circle.

Time taken O(x) to build structure
O(X  N log(X)) to search for smallest cluster

Answer (score 1):

Note: There are a bunch of answers for your second question (which will probably reap bigger benefits), but I'm only referring to your first one, i.e. what data to use without changing the algorithm.

There, I think that your choice using a vector is already pretty good, because in general vectors offer the best payload/overhead ratio and also the fastest iteration. In order to find out specific bottlenecks, use a profiler, otherwise you are only guessing. With large vectors, there are a few things to avoid though:

- Overallocation, this wastes space.
- Underallocation, this causes copying when the vector is grown to the necessary size.
- Copying.